# Time format does not insert correctly into database

Tags: php, database

Code below adds date in correct format but hours/minutes/seconds are inserted as 00:00:00.

```
$timestamp[] = 'date("2017-12-31 21:01:50")';
```

**$i** because I have this inside a a loop.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (post_id, username, content, timestamp, likes) 
VALUES ('$post_id[$i]', '$username[$i]', '$content[$i]', $timestamp[$i], 
'$likes[$i]')";
```

**Result:**
[image: Result]

Comment: `'date("2017-12-31 21:01:50")'` why the single quotes? those shouldn't be there.

Comment: The argument to `date()` is supposed to be a format string.

Comment: You date function should be like this `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`, and as @FunkFortyNiner why are you wrapping it with single quotes? it's treated as a string

Comment: Presumably the idea is to run the mysql `date()` function, not the PHP one. The problem with that is that the whole point of that function is to only return the **date**, not a **datetime**, which is why the time portion is being lost.

Comment: @iainn Right. I'd say that is not far from an answer.

Comment: this questioin's unclear and where the OP is in all this, is unknown.

Comment: Hi, I removed single quotations as you guys advised but now i'm getting 
      Error inserting row: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '21:01:50, '3')' at line 1 **The table type is timestamp**

Comment: if you want the current time of the insert, just use `NOW()`

Comment: I understand where the issue was. I passed into database as a simple string instead of date(). I'm using date later with posting post with current timestamp and works fine. Cheers for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's [`date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function returns a date *without a time portion*, which is why it's getting truncated to midnight.

You should be able to ignore the call to `date` entirely, and just pass the raw string - it's already in [a format that MySQL will understand](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

```
$timestamp[] = '2017-12-31 21:01:50';

$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (post_id, username, content, timestamp, likes) 
VALUES ('$post_id[$i]', '$username[$i]', '$content[$i]', '$timestamp[$i]', '$likes[$i]')";
```

(Note the added quotes around the `$timestamp` variable)

You should also look into using [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1), rather than building up your SQL string manually. It'd be both a security and readability benefit.

Comment: Yeah, figured out before you posted this. I just ignored it and added as you shown as simple string. I'm not doing anything later with this because my posts are generating timestamp anyway and adding that to database. Many thanks!